# Check the maximum memory size allocated in node.js

Tags: node.js, memory, process, heap-memory

We can get the memory usage from process object of node.js. If I set the --max-old-space-size while starting my node.js app, will it be reflected into the process memory usage? In which process object's variable I can get the max old space that I gave in the argv?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can print it using `process.memoryUsage()`. The response will be:
`rss: Resident Set Size, it is the total memory allocated for the process execution
heapTotal: is the total size of the allocated heap
heapUsed: is the actual memory used during the execution of the process`